# optimize my loop to return instead of doing 10 queries

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, pdo

I have a limited number of students (10) returned in an array in the below variable,

$result variable is a array, it contains student ID's like the example below

```
Array ( 
[student1] => 4 
[student2] => 1 
[student3] => 3 
[student4] => 2 
[student5] => 5 
[student6] => 10 
[student7] => 12 
[student8] => 16 
[student9] => 17 
[student10] => 18 
)
```

**what i tried**

```
$values = implode(", ", $result);
$sql = "SELECT sub1, sub2 FROM students WHERE students.id IN (" . $values . ")";

try{
    $db = new db();
    $db = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);

    $subject = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $db = null;
    if(empty($subject)) {
        $response->getBody()->write
        ('{"error":{"message":"Invalid Request}}');
    } else {
        $subject = json_decode(json_encode($subject), True);
        if (in_array("BIO", $subject))
          {
            return true;
          }
        else
          {
            return false;
          }
     print_r($subject);
    }
  } catch(PDOException $e) {}
```

I am sure How i can be optimize my query in one instead of looping 10 queries

Comment: Use the `IN()` clause, it's much more efficient than running a single query inside your loop.

Comment: can you show me how pls @BenM I am a newbie in all this

Comment: Putting the different subjects they are enrolled in into columns in the student table really breaks normalization and will probably cause you other troubles as you continue developing this. You should consider putting the enrollments into a separate table that maps student ids to courses for a given term.

Comment: thank you @Don'tPanic i agree with you, but its not a scalable project and limited to always 10 students and 2 subs for each, need to figure out how to do it in the way they provided me the db

Comment: Okay, just thought it was worth mentioning. Good luck!

Comment: @Don'tPanic can you help me with it please ?

Comment: I haven't tried to answer because I'm not clear enough on the requirement. What determines which subjects each student is supposed to have?

Comment: @Don'tPanic its just a static list of rules for each student number, i placed the first 3 as an example in my question

Comment: So you have something like an array with `[1 => 'BIO', 2 => 'MATH', ...` ?

Comment: there are not in an array just a list of conditions, i can place them in an array if it makes it easier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152650/discussion-between-mirvatj-and-dont-panic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do the query once you can make a request like this :

```
$values = implode(", ", $result);
$sql = "SELECT sub1, sub2 FROM students WHERE students.id IN (" . $values . ")";
```

This will return you all your students with one request

EDIT : removed the foreach, thanks Don't Panic

Comment: this only returned the first students sub1 and sub2

Comment: That foreach loop is a really long-winded way to do `$values = implode(", ", $result);`

Comment: try to print $values to make sure you have all the ids

Comment: and the query still only returns the first student's sub1 and sub2 and not all the sudents ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152657/discussion-between-mirvatj-and-momo-kebab).